# Maintenance page on apache 7

Tags: apache

I want to redirect to a maintenance page when my apache server is down.I tried through

> htacess

and nothing worked.. Please direct me to some working blog.

Thanks...

Comment: "Apache 7"?  Do you mean "Apache Tomcat 7"?

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` file contains no executable program code to do some activities. If you want to show a webpage then you need a running webserver. If you have no one bad luck. 
Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98106/automated-apache-server-maintenance-page?rq=1) about the technicel enviroment to reach your goal.

Edit: I found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183444/maintenance-page-forwarding-with-htaccess-does-not-work-for-proxied-material?rq=1) about this topic, though the same thing is the use of an additional webserver.

Comment: A java WEB application contains code that will be executed on server. Some server side code generate the HTML output. The servlet engine implie the user/browser that you called a website.